# PySide6 QScintilla binding

Tags: python, pyside6, qscintilla

I know there is no official link between qscintilla and pyside6, but I would like to know if there is any alternative or unofficial port.

In search of information, I found only an empty repository http://gitorious.org/pyside-qscintilla and (as I understand it) a build script https://github.com/LuaDist/scintilla/tree/master/qt/ScintillaEditPy

Comment: It's [officially dead](https://groups.google.com/g/scintilla-interest/c/cAHwmGmU9Ho/m/mtHCK5aAAQAJ) and hasn't really been supported for many years. If you want qscintilla python bindings, you will have to switch to [pyqt6](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/).

Comment: But is there any alternative in this case?

Comment: QScintilla is a project owned and maintained by [Riverbank Computing](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/), which also produces PyQt. Thus, strictly speaking, there can ***never*** be a PySide version, due to imcompatible licences. The best you can hope for is low-level python bindings of the underlying [Scintilla control](https://www.scintilla.org/). But really, it's off-topic to ask for software recommendations on SO. You can [search for pyside/scintilla](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22PySide%22+%22Scintilla%22) just as well as anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ekhmoro, there are probably never been a `QScintilla` version of the `Scintilla` control.

However, here are a list of my suggested alternative text editors:

- PyQode: claimed to be the *"alternative of the QScintilla control"*, however the official Qt port, Qode, is achieved by the authors (https://github.com/pyQode/pyqode.qt). The Python port of Qode seems still activating by the authors, but it's almost dead (the latest release, 2.8.0, is about 8 years ago). Official **source code** link: https://github.com/pyQode/pyqode.python. Official **installation** link: https://pypi.org/project/pyqode3-core/, via `pip install pyqode3-core`.
- qutepart: claims to support both PyQt and PySide version, however it seems that only PyQt is supported; but you can translate the source code (https://github.com/andreikop/qutepart) into `PySide`. Translate `pyqtSlot` into `Slot` and `pyqtSignal` into `Signal`, etc.
- Implement your own?

Yes, you can definitely implement your own `QsciScintilla` component with just one PySide (without any additional libraries!) See the example page below:

> https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6.2/examples/example_widgets__codeeditor.html

1. Adjust the font **by the default system's *monospace* font** by:

```cpp
QFont monospace = QFont();
monospace.setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace);
textEdit::setFont(monospace);
// This will lead the program figuring what 
// font should it use by itself.
```

```py
monospace: QFont = QFont()
monospace.setStyleHint(QFont.Monospace)
textEdit.setFont(monospace)
# This will lead the program figuring what
# font should it use by itself.
```

2. For syntax highlighting,

Refer to the following link. You will find a way that perfectly combines `QTextCharFormat` with `QPlainTextEdit`, via `QSyntaxHighlighter`.

> https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_richtext_syntaxhighlighter.html

These simple little code are just *equivalent to* those bulky `QsciLexer*`.

3. For other features

You might like to compare the feature of `QScintilla` and the Qt Rich Text engine. In this case, [Manuals](https://brdocumentation.github.io/qscintilla/classQsciScintilla.html) are your good friends. You can always check the documentation and see the similar stuff between `PySide::Qt-RichText` and `Qsci::QsciScintilla`. For instance,

```py
qsci_editor.setWrapMode(QsciScintilla.WrapWord)
# are equivalent to
pyside_editor.setWordWrapMode(QTextOption.WordWrap)
# While QTextOption::NoWrap == QsciScintilla::WrapNone;, etc.
```

> And finally, don't forget you have StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Scintilla has been working with Qt and C++ for a long time - the binding is in the official Scintilla source code and it is under the [Scintilla license](https://www.scintilla.org/License.txt) (wikipedia calls this license the [Historical Permission Notice and Disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Permission_Notice_and_Disclaimer)). You don't need QScintilla from Riverbank Computing for that.

For using Scintilla with PySide6 you can try [my simple binding](https://gitlab.com/iborco-pyside/pyside6-scintilla) - you'll need to build your own wheel and I have tested the binding only on windows with PySide6 6.6 and Python 3.12. I've released my binding under MIT.

Somebody also made a [feature request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1121) on bugreports.qt.io - you can also wait and see if the Qt Company will decide to implement the binding, but there has been no activity there for more than a year.

[screenshot of pyside6 scintilla demo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxA3Z.png)